# Facing issues while launching demo for Oculus SDK 0.6.0.1

Tags: oculus

I am facing below exception while launching the Oculus SDK 0.6.0.1 demo program.

**Exception Info
Exception report file: C:\Users\Exception Report (2015-06-26 12.41.23).txt
Exception minidump file: C:\Users\Exception Minidump (2015-06-26 12.41.23).mdmp
Time (GMT): 2015/06/26 12:41:23
Time (local): 2015/06/26 18:11:23
Thread name: (not available)
Thread handle: 0x000000d8
Thread sys id: 976 (0x3d0)
Exception instruction address: 0x0ff4f677 (see callstack below)

**Exception description: ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x00000000**
Exception location: ovr_WaitTillTime (59911)**

below is my app and system Info :

App Info
Process path: C:\Users\Downloads\ovr_sdk_win_0.6.0.0\OculusSDK\Samples\OculusWorldDemo\Release\OculusWorldDemo.exe
App format: 32 bit
App version info not present

System Info
OS name: Windows 7, version: 6.1 build 7601, 32 bit, platform id: 2, service pack: Service Pack 1
Debugger present: no
Processor count: 4
Processor type: x86
Processor level: 6
Processor revision: 10759
Memory load: 87%
Total physical memory: 3240 MiB
Available physical memory: 389 MiB
Total page file memory: 6480 MiB
Available page file memory: 2323 MiB
Total virtual memory: 2047 MiB
Free virtual memory: 1974 MiB

Can someone help me to understand what to do, to fix this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any info about your video hardware & drivers; the first thing I'd try is upgrading them. Also try upgrading to the latest Oculus 0.7.0.1 runtime.